# Mirroring: Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1431

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, mirroring

We had a mirroring currently going to DR on SQL Server 2014. The server to the principal crashed and database was restored to new server. We are trying to proceed with the mirroring however upon click of "start mirroring" button, we are getting this error:

> Neither the partner nor the witness server instance for database "DBName" is available. Reissue the command when at least one of the instances becomes available. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1431)

Comment: Was mirroring setup before DR? Sounds like you trying to mirror after DR. \

Comment: Did you reconfigure mirroring from the New Server where you restore database?

Comment: After failover are you using the same SQL instances that were previously in the configuration?  The message suggests that you are trying to start it on a server that was not set up for it (i.e. the original principal, on failover would become the mirror partner).

Comment: I recreated the end points so i expect the new server to assume the principal role.